# Location does not update in emulator

Tags: android-studio

i am having issues with getting locations. I do not know if it is an emulator problem because it is not easy to test on my phone.
**The problem:**
in my app i can (of course) get locations. To test this in the emulator i specified a number of locations (see picture). When in my app i request a location it perfectly returns the selected location. But when i then again (with leaving the screen) add another location (in between i changed location in the controls windows from (lets say) line 1 to line 2 (and pressed "SET LOCATION") but it still get the first location back.
I tried flushing the buffer but that does not help. So something must be sticking i just cannot figure out what
[![emulator screen][1]][1]

and the code

```
    private fun getSingleLocation() {

    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
    mFusedLocationClient.flushLocations()
    mFusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, null)
        .addOnSuccessListener { location ->
            if (location != null) {
                mLocation = location
                mListener?.onLocationChanged()
            } else {
                mListener?.onFailure()
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.e("Exception", exception.message.toString())
            mListener?.onFailure()
        }
}
```

now the question is, is something wrong with my code of is this an emulator bug?
i really hope the code or it will mean a lot of running around to test my app :-)

Answer (score 0):

today had time to "run around" and test if this is a emulator issue or a problem in my app.
Turns out the emulator is not working correctly. The App does not buffer and picks a new (current) location every time.